# Why do some Poedit hotkeys not work on Kubuntu (e.g. Ctrl+Enter)?

Tags: shortcut-keys, kubuntu

I installed Poedit on my Kubuntu 14.10 and some keyboard shortcuts do not work. Most noteably the most important shortcut Ctrl+Enter to go to the next item does not work. Also Ctrl+Up/Down does not work. However man other hotkeys such as Ctrl+U (mark fuzzy) works just fine. I can also "manually" go over the menu "Go -> Done and Next" or even with Alt+G (opens Go menu) then "D".

What could possibly interfere with the Ctrl+Enter shortcut? How can I test that? Could this have to do with KDE?

Answer (score 0):

> Could this have to do with KDE?

Quite possibly, although my first guess would be Ubuntu's general habit of replacing normal GTK+ UI with custom — and very, very broken — code. Case in point: the global menu, which was broken for YEARS for perfectly valid wxGTK code (affecting Audacity, Poedit and others) because they don't care much about compatibility. In 14.04, this code finally got *relatively* stable, but some issues remain. It's entirely possible 14.10 re-broke something yet again. `</rant>`

All I know is that it all works just fine in Poedit 1.8 on the "normal" Ubuntu 14.04.